# How to make an enemy stop when he enter the required distance to shoot

Tags: unity-game-engine

The problem that i have is that when the enemy enters the range to shoot it stops and never follows the player again even if the player gets out of the shooting range. To detect if the player entered the shooting range I have made a sphere collider for the enemy.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyWithRifleMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject player;
    private NavMeshAgent nav;
    private bool playerInRange = false;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").gameObject;
        nav = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(playerInRange)
        {
           nav.SetDestination(transform.position);
        }
        else if(playerInRange == false)
           nav.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerInRange = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggetExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You misspelled `OnTriggetExit`. It should be `OnTriggerExit`

Comment: Well it can be easily seen that i am new. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks all fine, except there is one typo. Replace `OnTriggetExit` with `OnTriggerExit`, and it should work!

Also, in my opinion it is easier to get the distance between the enemy and the player by doing `playerInRange = (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player) <= range`.